# Makefile not executing the commands as expected

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I'm using the following Makefile, which should check whether the files are in some directory `*.rpm`, if the files hasn't been found i'm going to execute some command (run a script or make the rpm)

Here's a snippet from my Makefile

```
include /home/user/workspace/test/exec_recipe.mk
export BUILD_LOGS_DIR = $(CURDIR)/build_logs
.PHONY: my_rpm
libpdutil_rpm:
            @echo "Making target 'libpdutil_rpm'. Time: $$(date +%T)"
            cd /home/user/workspace/test/build/test && $(call exec_recipe,$(ls /home/user/workspace/test/build/test/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64d/*.rpm) || $(./test.sh),test.log,)
            @echo "Finished making target 'my_rpm'. Time: $$(date +%T)"
```

And here's the `exec_recipe.mk`

```
SHELL:=/bin/bash
exec_recipe = \
    echo "The logs dir is: $$BUILD_LOGS_DIR"; \
    log_name="$(2)"; \
    echo "The log name is $$log_name"; \
    cmd="$(1)"; \
    eval "$$cmd" 2>&1 | tee -a "$$BUILD_LOGS_DIR/$$log_name"; rc="$${PIPESTATUS[0]}"; \
    if [ $$rc = 0 ]; then \
        res="PASS"; \
    else \
        res="FAIL"; \
    fi; \
    flock $(SUMMARY) echo "Making target '$@': $$res" >> $(SUMMARY); \
    exit $$rc
```

So the problem is when it's reaching the execution of the `exec_recipe.mk` it giving me some errors:

`/bin/bash: eval: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token`||'
`/bin/bash: eval: line 0:` || '

I'm sure that i'm doing something wrong..
I need the helper make file, because i'm using it for other purposes as well

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape *all* the dollar signs that you don't want make to interpret.  You've forgotten to escape the dollar signs in the arguments to `$(call exec_recipe,...)`:

```
        cd /home/user/workspace/test/build/test && $(call exec_recipe,$$(ls /home/user/workspace/test/build/test/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64d/*.rpm) || $$(./test.sh),test.log,)
```

I'm not sure what the final comma is for but whatever.

Comment: Maybe you propose a better solution, I want to check whether the RPMs were built or downloaded , if they're not there I'll execute the make rpm of my code , or any build tool which I have , I need the execute_recipe.mk , because it's being in use in other places, I could even use a `test -n $(find path -name '*.rpm' -print -quit)`

Comment: I don't understand your comment here.  I explained what was wrong in your makefile, in my answer.  If you fix that it may work (I didn't try it myself so I can't be sure).  It's not the way I would have done it, but you didn't ask that.  If you make the fix as I suggested and that doesn't fix the problem, then you should edit your question to describe the new problem, or ask a new question.